Stroboscopic Jobs page
Visiting https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/gft and attempting to scroll creates some fireworks on my Chrome on MacOS Sonoma (browser in incognito mode, no extensions).
I seem to be unable to upload a video here, but I have made it available at https://gist.github.com/tripleee/d1f6961eb025145ffe7f9bd2c0b2386e
In the video, I am attempting to scroll down slightly using the mouse wheel, but the banner across the top updates and sort of drags everything back to the top. In the final sequence, it's flickering wildly while I'm doing nothing.
This is a 15-inch 2018 MacBook Pro (2.2 GHz 6-core Intel i7; Radeon Pro 555X 4GH / Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB)

I get a similar effect in FF 130 on Windows 10 when I scroll down using the arrow keys and the mouse wheel (well, touchpad two finger swipe, which should be equivalent). The top flickers really fast for a bit and eventually I am able to scroll down. Seems to happen once per page load - if I scroll down and get past the flickering, then scrolling up to the top and down again doesn't re-trigger it. But if I scroll down -> refresh (page re-opens midway down again) -> scroll to top -> scroll down then it flickers again.

Just for a counter comment, I don't have the issue on Windows 11, Firefox 130.0. Could a browser extension be affecting it (seems unlikely); might be worth testing by turning them off.

off-topic, that's a pretty interesting solution to put the video on github. I would have never thought of that.

Cannot reproduce on Windows 10, FF 130.0 or Chrome 128.0.6613.138

More reproduction information: seems to be related to the left menu. I have it disabled and I could reproduce the bug. If I enable it (or log out - it's there for anonymous users) then I can't reproduce this any more.

Even with the left menu turned off, I couldn't replicate; I gave it a go on my sock puppet and logged out. Odd indeed.
